# PHP - While there was no error, datas are not inserting or selecting from database on live server

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Everything was working fine on the local server but once I uploaded it on live-server, it wouldn't insert or select from the database. I can't sign-up or sign-in. Any idea? Here's my Database configuration:

```
class Database {

    public function connect() {

        try {

            $dbhost = "localhost"; //recently tried 127.0.0.1
            $dbuser = "tcorfns**_bams**"; //hidden info
            $dbname = "tcorfns**_bams**";
            $dbpass = "Offs**";

            $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);

            return $db;


        } catch(PDOException $err) {

            echo "Error: ".$err->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

Here's my Sign up configuration:

```
public function create($data) {

        $fname      = $data['fname'];
        $lname      = $data['lname'];
        $email      = $data['email'];
        $phone      = $data['phone'];
        $state      = $data['state'];
        $password   = $data['password'];
        $password2  = $data['password2'];

        if(empty($fname) || empty($lname) || empty($email) || empty($phone) || empty($state) || empty($password) || empty($password2)) {

            $msg = "All fields are required";
            return $msg;
        }

        if($password != $password2) {

            $msg = "Password must match";
            return $msg;
        }

        if($this->checkUser($email)) {

            $msg = "User already exists, please signin!";
            return $msg;
        }
        else {

            $pass = Helper::make($password);
            $ref_code = $this->ReferralCode();

            $query = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO Users(fname, lname, email, phone, state, password, ref_code) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            $values= ([$fname, $lname,$email, $phone, $state, $pass, $ref_code]);
            $proceed = $query->execute($values);

            if($proceed) {

                $msg = "Registration successful, check your email for verification details";
                return $msg;

            }

            else {

                $msg = "Registration failed";
                return $msg;
            }

            
        }
    }
```

Here's my Sign In configuration:

```
public function login($data) {

        $email = $data['email'];
        $password = $data['password'];

        if(empty($email) || empty($password)) {

            $msg = "You must input email and password";
            return $msg; 
        }
        
        if(!$this->checkUser($email)) {

            $msg = "User with this email is not exist";
            return $msg;
        }

        else {

        $email = $data['email'];
        $password = $data['password'];

        $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT email, password FROM Users WHERE `email` = '$email' ");
        $proceed = $query->execute();
        $row = $query->fetch();

        if($proceed)  {

            if(password_verify($password, $row['password'])) {

                $re = new Functions();
                $_SESSION['connected'] = $email;
                $re::redirect('../dashboard/');

            } else {

                $msg = "You have entered incorrect email or password";
                return $msg;
                
            }

        } else {

            $msg = "Something went wrong, please try again";
            return $msg;
        }
    }
}
```

How can i get this fix because everything is working fine on local host

Comment: check server error log!

Comment: @Marty -- Was not showing any error relating to the issue

Comment: If everything works fine on localhost, try to find out if you can connect the database or not. If you are just trying to learn and this is not a business enviroment, try to echo something on your connection function. Maybe there is something wrong with password and username encodings just try to echo them and make sure they are correct and you are able to connect. and also check your table names.

Comment: Also please try `"$dbuser", "$dbpass"`

Comment: Enable [PDO exception mode](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#errors) otherwise things could fail silently. Also read the note about there being no reason to use try/catch. Realistically, if your attempt to connect to the DB fails, can your application continue to work usefully? Probably not...so then there should be no reason to catch the exception there - just let it fail. And also, don't echo exception data deliberately into the user-facing output - that's a security risk. Let PHP handle the error and then either display or log it as per its config (in live servers, only logging should be used)

Comment: P.S. "wouldn't" and "can't" are not useful problem descriptions. Describe what the code _does_ do instead of what you expected it to do. Just saying it didn't do something doesn't allow us to fully understand its behavior, or diagnose anything from symptoms.

Comment: `$this->db->prepare("SELECT email, password FROM Users WHERE \`email\` = '$email' ")` ...this code is vulnerble to SQL injection attacks. You need to parameterise the email variable, just like you are parameterising all the variables when you run the INSERT query in the signup script. I'm not really sure why you parameterised one query but not the other...you've only done half a job!

Comment: The query should be `$this->db->prepare("SELECT email, password FROM Users WHERE email = ?"); $proceed = $query->execute([$email]);`

Comment: @ADyson -- Thanks for the SQL injection attacks precaution, I will fix that. The above code supposed let user signup and signin but it was not selecting or inserting on live-server, but it was working on local server. I got this: **Error: SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'bamstatus'@'localhost' (using password: YES)**. Alhough I added password

Comment: @NervousDev -- I do not understand where and why I should add this: **"$dbuser", "$dbpass"**. Please can you elaborate

Comment: Presumably then it wasn't the correct password. Either that or the mysql user account isn't set up for access from `@localhost` - remember that mysql user accounts are host-sensitive. If you're unsure what the correct SQL connection details are for your live server, or what setup steps you may need to take, then check in your hosting account (e.g. in phpMyAdmin or cPanel if you can), or seek assistance from your hosting provider - they may also have documentation which explains what connection info to provide, as well.

Comment: @NervousDev those variable are already strings, so that won't make any difference. I've no idea why you would expect that to help, and you didn't explain your comment.

Comment: @ADyson -- Thought I could contact the host in this case ?

Comment: Yes you are able to connect, but each user account has to be enabled to accept logins from specific hostnames. https://www.prisma.io/dataguide/mysql/authentication-and-authorization/user-management-and-authentication#understanding-how-mysql-defines-and-interprets-user-accounts

Comment: @ADyson -- I saw this on error_log: **Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in /home/*****/status.bambam**de.com/App/Controllers/Users.php:77**

Line 77:  **$query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE `email` = '$email'");** 

I think something is wrong with **emailChecker** function. It pointed to to it twice

Comment: How I check if user already exist: 

**public function checkUser($email) {

        $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE `email` = '$email'");
        $query->execute();
        $check = $query->fetchColumn();
           
           return $check;
    }**

Comment: That's happening because your connection object is null. Your connection object is null because you couldn't log in because of the permission problem. The second error is just a symptom of the first And your code is continuing to try and operate despite the connection failing, because of what I told you about above - you're catching a connection error (which should be fatal) and then letting the code carry on as if nothing was wrong!! Remove the try/catch rubbish from the `connect()` function (and read that link I provided you with earlier, to understand more)

Comment: @KwiksellerTechnologies  `"$dbuser", "$dbpass"`  about this: When I had the same sort of problem it was kind of my solution even tho I know those are string and it seems like it doesn't effect but that was my solution for my problem. I see a same sort of problem here(Everything works fine on localhost but doesnt on live) Thats why I shared. You can use it like this =>   `$db = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", "$dbuser", "$dbpass");`

Comment: @NervousDev whatever happened to you must have been some sort of coincidence. It's simple to demonstrate that putting quote marks around the variable names makes absolutely no difference to the contents of what the PDO class receives - demo: https://3v4l.org/A1ZtV